# Import region stack configuration in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-regions

I configured a region manually with some services like EC2, APIGW etc.

I am wondering if I can export this configuration (via aws-cli for example) and import it in CloudFormation as a template

Thanks for the support

Comment: Not all of them in one go, no - please read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html